# How to create PIPE accessible from remote computers in .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, pipe

How to create PIPE accessible from remote computers in .NET 4.0? And how to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just used NamedPipe{Client,Server}Stream in System.IO.Pipes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298714.aspx

Sample is given @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx